# Can't connect to RDS postgresql instance from EC2 ubuntu instance (python psycopg2)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-rds, continuous-deployment

I have a postgresql db on AWS that is up and works on my local testing server.

I wrote a CI/CD code that connects to EC2 (Ubuntu t2.micro) and clones the code repository, and when I launch the app, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
from app.routes.company_controller import company_app
File "/home/ubuntu/back-end/app/routes/company_controller.py", line 11, in <module>
db_connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_param)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in 
connect conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The code works on local but here what it looks like:

```
db_param = config_var()
db_connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_param)
```

config_var() returns a dictionnary with all the information to connect to the db from environnement variables, and from the logs, it is good.

Here is the bash script that installs/launches the app:

```
  "git clone https://$back_user:$back_token@gitlab.com/blabla \
  && cd blabla \
  && sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip \
  && sudo apt-get -y install libpq-dev python-dev \
  && pip install -r requirements.txt \
  && python3 app.py"
```

In the requirements.txt I have a line for psycopg2.
Last information but not least, I opened all the ports to any IP address on this whole earth to anyone to make this learning process easier, but I can't get rid of that error.

Edit: as asked in comment, more details:
This is what config_var() does:

```
def config_var():
return {
    "database": os.environ.get('DATABASE'),
    "user": os.environ.get('USER'),
    "password": os.environ.get('PASSWORD'),
    "host": os.environ.get('HOST'),
    "port": os.environ.get('PORT')
}
```

And here's how I set the variables in the bash script (I run this in the CI pipeline after connecting to EC2):

```
 "export USER=$user \
 && export DATABASE=$database \
 && export PASSWORD=$password \
 && export HOST=$host \
 && export PORT=$port"
```

Comment: What is in `config_var()` exactly? The error indicates it is trying to connect to Postgres via a local socket on the EC2 server. It isn't trying to connect to the RDS server at all.

Comment: Tried to add more details in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, the problem was that my variables weren't properly set in the ubuntu session.

What led me to the error was the psycopg2 documentation, and the comment above.
["host – database host address (defaults to UNIX socket if not provided)"](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect)